# How does the Joule-Kelvin effect apply to the liquefaction process of Hydrogen? Why do we need to cool Hydrogen before taking advantages of this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I am currently writing a report around Hydrogen at a first year university level. On the below section i discuss the liquefaction process of Hydrogen and how the Joule-Kelvin effect is used in the liquefaction process. Have i described this correctly?

"Liquefaction of Hydrogen requires copious amounts of energy as it must be stored at 20.15k and be maintained at this temperature. The liquefaction process takes advantage of the Joule-Kelvin (Joule-Thomson) effect, this effect states if we force a gas through an orifice then as it expands it becomes cooler. To achieve this the system must be adiabatic meaning no heat is transferred between environments as the enthalpy of the system must remain constant; enthalpy referring to the total heat content of said system. This process for most gasses takes place at room temperature but Hydrogen must first be cooled to below 346.15k to take advantage of the phenomenon. This in turn effects the cost as liquid nitrogen is often used to get the Hydrogen to the correct temperature."

Secondly why does Hydrogen need to be cooled first? I believe it has something to do with the "long-range forces in these gases are unusually weak" but am finding it difficult to understand exactly what this means.

Redone section below:

“The liquefaction process takes advantage of the Joule-Kelvin (Joule-Thomson) effect, this effect states if we force a gas through an orifice then as it expands it becomes cooler. To achieve this the system must be adiabatic meaning no heat is transferred between environments as the enthalpy of the system must remain constant; enthalpy referring to the total heat content of said system. Meaning specially constructed vessels are used to try and maintain a constant enthalpy. Additionally, this process for most gasses takes place at room temperature but Hydrogen must first be cooled to ~200k to take advantage of the phenomenon. This temperature is known as the maximum inversion temperature. Hydrogen above this temperature would actually heat up upon expansion as it would do at any temperature above ~200k. This detrimentally effects Hydrogen viability as a fuel as some form of pre-cooling is required to liquify the gas. Translating to higher energy consumption and increased costs. Primarily liquid nitrogen is used as a coolant which must be either purchased or produced. When considering Hydrogens viability as a fuel this must be considered. This factor increases the energy required to get the Hydrogen into a form with the energy densities required to compete with current technologies.”

Comment: "This process for most gasses takes place at room temperature but Hydrogen must first be cooled to below **346.15k** to take advantage of the phenomenon."  I would definitely check this park again.

Comment: Google *Joule Thomson inversion temperature*. The inversion temperature or hydrogen is around 200K not 346.15K.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. i think I've managed to wrap my head around things a little better. Would this be a clearer way to state this? (Added a redone section above) Really appreciate the help!